# Explicit homeomorphism between $L^p$ and Sobolev Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

From the Anderson-Kadec theorem, we know that all separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are homeomorphic.  I'm wondering, is there an explicit such homeomorphism between $W^{p,k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $L^2(\mu,\mathbb{R}^n)$? 
Here, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W^{p,k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Sobolev space of "functions" with $k$ weak derivates with finite $p^{th}$ norm.  If possible, an explicit *bi-Lipschitz* homeomorphism would be most interesting.

I know that the Fourier transform does the job when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $k$ is sufficiently well-chosen, but I was wondering what is possible in this setting.

Comment: You already know that the Sobolev space and $L_p(\lambda)$ are explicily linearly isomorphic; also $L_2(\mu)$ and $L_2(\lambda)$ are isometric (via orthonormal bases, hence (?)  explicitly); finally $L_p(\mu)$ and $L_2(\mu)$ are homeomorphic via the Mazur map $f\mapsto |f|^{p/2}\operatorname{sign}(f)$. (Mazur's paper is in Studia Math.\ 1, 83--85 (1929).)

Comment: @DirkWerner Yes but the Isomorphism between the Sobolev space and $L_p(\lambda)$ is practical like the Mazur map in the sense that a function must first be decomposed in terms of an basis and then mapped.  Right?  Is there a direct transformation does the job (even if it's non-linear like the Mazur map)?

Comment: @AIM_BPB For the isomorphism between the Sobolev space and $L_p$ one uses Fourier multipliers, right? So only the isomorphism between the  $L_2$-spaces requires the choice of a noncanonical basis.

Comment: Actually I'm not familiar with Fourier multipliers.  (now this may have become basic) but how would you do that?

Comment: Please take a look at Wojtaszczyk's ``Banach Spaces For Analysts'', Proposition III.A.3 (which deals with the periodic Sobolev space).